# Display renamed files in GitWeb

Tags: git, gitweb

I rename some files with `git mv`. Normally `git status` would detect this and display that these files were renamed. However in GitWeb these files are displayed as deleted and created with new name. Is there a way to tell GitWeb to try to detect renamed files? Maybe, some other web-based Git viewer can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git [doesn't track renames](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F). It actually treats the following two operations in exactly the same way:

1. Rename a file within Git:

   - `git mv foo bar`
2. Delete a file and then add a new one with the same content:

   - `cp foo bar`
   - `git rm foo`
   - `git add bar`

Some tools will display something along the lines of "`foo` renamed to `bar`", but it's just a guess based on similar content. Other tools will display "deleted `foo` and added `bar`". To Git they're the same thing.

The [`gitweb.conf` manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitweb.conf.html) lists a configuration directive that can be used to change how renames are detected:

> `@diff_opts`
>
> Rename detection options for git-diff and git-diff-tree. The default is ('-M'); set it to ('-C') or ('-C', '-C') to also detect copies, or set it to () i.e. empty list if you don’t want to have renames detection.
>
> Note that rename and especially copy detection can be quite CPU-intensive. Note also that non git tools can have problems with patches generated with options mentioned above, especially when they involve file copies ('-C') or criss-cross renames ('-B').

It looks like the default value of `('-M')` is what you want ([from the `git-diff` manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)):

> `-M[<n>]`
> `--find-renames[=<n>]`
>
> Detect renames. If `n` is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, `-M90%` means git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes `0.5`, and is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`.

Perhaps the files you're comparing also have enough different content that they are not being detected as a rename?

Comment: Apparently, the default gitweb.conf supplied with Debian changes that behaviour to `@diff_opts = ();`